# imMarkerClick Android Google Maps API v2 intent to another activity

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I am currently developing a map application on android. I was wondering if marker can act as a button. Like for example if i can create an intent and do to another activity when marker is clicked.

For example:

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

            if (marker.equals(startPerc)) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SpecificRoom.class);
                String bn = startPerc.getSnippet();
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, bn);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            return false;
        }
```

The code does not show any errors but it does nothing when marker is clicked. I am not even sure if markers provide that kind of functionality. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: it is probably not passing your `if statement`, did you put breakpoints in and step through to see what happens??

Comment: No, i have not. Because i was not sure if markers can sent intents. Can they? If they can the problem might be somewhere else in my code. But i am not asking for problems in my code.. Do you know if it's possible to do such thing with markers? Thanks!

Comment: there is no such thing as Markers sending intents, you send intents. All you are doing is doing something when a marker is clicked so yes you can send an intent when you click a marker like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is onMarkerClick() you can use, there is no reason you could not send any intents, you can do whatever you'd do in any other function of yours. Just remove the if statement to be sure the inner body gets called, and you are good to go.